# Deletion of table using Hibernate don't work

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

In my spring project, Hibernate is used to manage the access to the database. For this, I have the tradicional schema using Entity and Dao classes, which are used by my service classes.  am facing problems when I need remove a row from some table in my database. For instance, follow the code below:

**remove.jsp**

```
<c:url value="/usuario/listagem" var="listagem"/>

<c:url value="/permissao/remove" var="removePermissao"/>
<form class="form" role="form" action="${removePermissao}" method="post">
<div class="alert alert-warning" id="pergunta">

    Tem certeza que quer excluir o grupo de permiss&otilde;es <strong><c:out value="${permissao.nome}"/></strong>?

  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<c:out value="${permissao.id}"/>">

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-link"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-link link" data-action="${listagem}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>
</div>
</form>

      <div id="yes" class="alert alert-success" style="display: none;">
        <strong>Pronto!</strong> Permiss&atilde;o excluida com sucesso.
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
      </div>

      <div id="not" class="alert alert-danger" style="display: none;">
        <strong>Erro!</strong> N&atilde;o foi possivel excluir a permiss&atilde;o.
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
      </div>
```

**method remove() from controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value="remove", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String remove(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    if(permissao.remove(request, response))
        return "yes";
    else
        return "not";
}
```

**method remove() from service class**

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#user, 'altera_permissao')")
@Transactional
public boolean altera(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    String id_usuario = request.getParameter("usuario");
    String id_permissao = request.getParameter("grupo");
    String possui = request.getParameter("possui");

    if(possui.equals("yes")) {
        Usuario user = usuario.findById(Integer.valueOf(id_usuario).intValue());
        user.getAutorizacao().add(grupo_permissao.findById(Integer.valueOf(id_permissao).intValue()));
        return usuario.merge(user);
    }
    else {
        Usuario user = usuario.findById(Integer.valueOf(id_usuario).intValue());
        int max = user.getAutorizacao().size();
        for(int i=0; i<max; i++) {
            if(user.getAutorizacao().get(i).equals(grupo_permissao.findById(Integer.valueOf(id_permissao).intValue()))) {
                user.getAutorizacao().set(i, null);
            }
        }
        return usuario.merge(user);
    }
}

@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#user, 'remove_permissao')")
@Transactional
public boolean remove(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    String id = request.getParameter("id");
    GrupoPermissao novo = grupo_permissao.findById(Integer.valueOf(id).intValue());
    novo.setPermissao(null);
    return grupo_permissao.remove(novo);
}
```

In the first method, altera(...), the second block of code from if...else should remove a permission fromthe user. The second method remove a role created by the user (roles in my project are a set of permissions).

The problem in first method is that when I try remove a row, a new one is inserted instead. In the second method, I am not able to remove the element because the system return an error of violation foreign key.

Anyone can help with some information of jow I should modify this method to accomplish the desired function?

ps.: my entity class related to the example above is:

**Permissao.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="permission")
public class Permissao {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="nome")
    private String nome;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

}
```

**GrupoPermissao.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="role")
public class GrupoPermissao {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="nome")
    private String nome;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="role_permissions", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="fk_role")}, inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="fk_permission")})
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private List<Permissao> permissao = new ArrayList<Permissao>();

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public List<Permissao> getPermissao() {
        return permissao;
    }

    public void setPermissao(List<Permissao> permissao) {
        this.permissao = permissao;
    }

}
```

**UPDATE 2**

My final code is this:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#user, 'altera_permissao')")
@Transactional
public boolean altera(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    String id_usuario = request.getParameter("usuario");
    String id_permissao = request.getParameter("grupo");
    String possui = request.getParameter("possui");

    if(possui.equals("not")) {
        Usuario user = usuario.findById(Integer.valueOf(id_usuario).intValue());
        user.getAutorizacao().add(grupo_permissao.findById(Integer.valueOf(id_permissao).intValue()));
        return usuario.merge(user);
    }
    else {
        Usuario user = usuario.findById(Integer.valueOf(id_usuario).intValue());
        int max = user.getAutorizacao().size();
        int index[] = new int[max];
        for(int i=0; i<max; i++)
            index[i] = -1;
        for(int i=0; i<max; i++) {
            String p_user = user.getAutorizacao().get(i).getNome();
            String p_comp = grupo_permissao.findById(Integer.valueOf(id_permissao).intValue()).getNome();
            System.out.println(i+"->"+p_user+"=="+p_comp);
            if(p_user.equals(p_comp)) {
                index[i] = i;
            }
        }
        for(int i=0; i<max; i++)
            if(index[i] >= 0)
                user.getAutorizacao().remove(i);
        return usuario.merge(user);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially you need to call session.getCurrentSession().delete(entity); to remove the entity using hibernate.

Or you can create a cutomer query using createQuery.

This is a great example of how to remove an object from table using hibernate:

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/hibernate/delete-persistent-object-with-hibernate/

EDIT 1:
Based on extra information provided where you want to remove permission relationship from user
then code you need to insert into either controller or pojo can be following:

```
User user = // allocate your user;
Permissao permissao = // allocate the permission you wish to remove

user.setPermissao(user.getPermissao().remove(permissaio);

then save the user object through saveOrUpdate() or Update() function.
```

This will remove the relationship to the permissao from the user. Keeps the user and permission in database.

Comment: But I don't want remove an entity, I want remove the relation this entity with your foreign key. In this example, the entity User have several Permissions. I want remove this permissions from the user, but keep the user and the permissions stored in the database (I want remove the proper rows from join table user_permission).

Comment: Ok so if you removing the relationship all you have to do is remove it from users List of permissao and then save the user object. That removes the link between user and permissao. Refer to answer for more information.

Comment: it's what I am doing now. But instead of delete, it's inserting a new row on the table in database.

Comment: In the code you have shown us you don't have any delete/remove from user. Can you advise which line in which file you do the removal of permission from the user? Otherwise if its not here then upload the code too.

Comment: the updated code is here: https://github.com/klebermo/lojavirtual/blob/master/src/main/java/com/spring/webapp/lojavirtual/acesso/service/PermissaoService.java

Comment: line 73:  user.getAutorizacao().remove(i);
line 74 (new):  <youruserservice>.<saveOrUpdatefunction>(user)
Do that and it will work. As long as youruserservice calls the relevant hibernate function to save or update the entity.
I can't see anywhere in your code that you are updating the user after you remove the permission. Double check that.

Comment: my function for update the user is the merge() function. I already am calling it, but, as I said, it's inserting a new row in the table.